# after fast pressing and resizing the window it showing wrong thing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a slider that should work as a small website (the slider itself is the website). He is working great untill you long-press the left or right arrow in the keyboard. Another problem is when you resizing the window. The slider is based on the window width, so if you resize the window the code have to change itself, and it doing it strangely.

The animation is performed by CSS3 `animation`. Please don't change the code that does work (I mean that if there is a better way I'll be happy to hear about her but I need that this code will stay on my website so change only what you must to change to make it work).

The HTML:

```
<div class="arrow" id="right_arrow"></div>
<div class="body">
    <div class="block" id="b1">
        <img src="http://1-ps.googleusercontent.com/h/www.web-gen.net/rain/images/xrain_al.png.pagespeed.ic.BMbYwGbMq7.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="block" id="b2">
        <img src="http://1-ps.googleusercontent.com/h/www.web-gen.net/rain/images/xrain_m.png.pagespeed.ic.H9sZUAPWyf.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="block" id="b3">
        <img src="http://1-ps.googleusercontent.com/h/www.web-gen.net/rain/images/xrain_s.png.pagespeed.ic.0jPd7y9jis.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="block" id="b4">
        <img src="http://1-ps.googleusercontent.com/h/www.web-gen.net/rain/images/xrain_l.png.pagespeed.ic.CcyCsd27jj.png" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="arrow" id="left_arrow" style="opacity: 0;"></div>
```

The CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/opensanshebrew.css);
 @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400, 700);
 html, body {
    background: transparent;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family:'Open Sans Hebrew', 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    direction: rtl;
}
.arrow {
    height: 23px;
    width: 20px !important;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -11.5px 0 0 0 !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-top: 0 !important;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s;
    transition: all 0.6s;
}
#right_arrow {
    background: url(http://www.web-gen.net/rain/images/arrow_r.png);
    right: 20px;
}
#left_arrow {
    background: url(http://www.web-gen.net/rain/images/arrow_l.png);
    left: 20px;
}
.block {
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: -1680px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s;
    transition: all 0.6s;
}
```

The JQ:

```
var width = $(document).width();

$(".block").css({
    "width": width + "px"
});
$(".body").css({
    "width": 4 * width + "px",
        "margin-right": "-" + 3 * width + "px"
});

var screens = 4;
var current = 1;

$("#right_arrow").click(function () {
    continuenext("right");
});

$("#left_arrow").click(function () {
    continuenext("left");
});

jwerty.key('arrow-right', function () {
    continuenext("right");
});

jwerty.key('arrow-left', function () {
    continuenext("left");
});

function continuenext(side) {
    if (side == "left" && current != 1) {
        current--;
        $(".body").css({
            "margin-right": 0 - width - Math.floor($(".body").css("margin-right").replace(/[A-Za-z$-]/g, ""))
        });
        $(".body").css({});
    } else if (side == "right" && current != 4) {
        current++;
        $(".body").css({
            "margin-right": width - Math.floor($(".body").css("margin-right").replace(/\D/g, ''))
        });
    }

    if (current == 4) $("#right_arrow").css({
        "opacity": 0
    });
    else $("#right_arrow").css({
        "opacity": 1
    });
    if (current == 1) $("#left_arrow").css({
        "opacity": 0
    });
    else $("#left_arrow").css({
        "opacity": 1
    });
}

$(document).resize(function () {
    if ($(document).width() != width) {
        width = $(document).width();
        $(".block").css({
            "width": width + "px"
        });
        $(".body").css({
            "width": 4 * width + "px",
                "margin-right": "-" + current - 1 * width + "px"
        });
    }
});
```

**I made a small change in the JS code** (the background color) **so take the code from the JSFiddle please**

the whole code in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sep5F/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your way of doing this is excessively complex.

I don't think you're interested in rewriting the design. The simplest fix I can come up with is to replace the way you set the margin-right:

```
if (side == "left" && current != 1) current--;
else current++;

$(".body").css({"margin-right": (current-4) * width});
```

The following may help with the resizing issue, consider replacing

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    if ($(document).width() != width) {
        width = $(document).width();
        $(".block").css({
            "width": width + "px"
        });
        $(".body").css({
            "width": 4 * width + "px",
                "margin-right": "-" + current - 1 * width + "px"
        });
    }
});
```

with

```
var resize_timeout;

function resize_elems(){
    if ($(document).width() != width) {
        width = $(document).width();
        $(".block").css({
            "width": width + "px"
        });
        $(".body").css({
            "width": 4 * width + "px",
                "margin-right": (current-4) * width
        });
    }
}

$(window).resize(function () {
    window.clearTimeout( resize_timeout );
    resize_timeout = window.setTimeout(resize_elems,100);
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: LOL Why didn't I thought about it? `:D` Thank you very much. The additional line is there 'cause I accidentally did copy and not cut as I should to do it. Still I have the resizing problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what the resizing issue is. Normally I bind this event to the window, not the document. Also, I don't like the idea of recalculating the width in the resize event - some browsers will calculate this 100s of times a second. To solve this, I would use a timeout. Anyway, it's not clear to me what the resizing issue is - do you mean that the height of the `.block` divs don't fit the window?